# Is there a MACRO to tell me whether Gcov is enabled?

Tags: gcov

I need to know whether Gcov is enabled at compile time.

I'm running Gcov on a program which calls "std::quick_exit()" at the end. So I need to manually call "__gcov_flush()" before exit to generate coverage files. But I don't want to compile the Gcov related function into normal binary. Is there any MACRO to tell me whether Gcov is enabled or some other way to get the information at compile time.